# AVD Manager ajuste no display

Tags: android, emulador, avd

[image: Como ajustar o display do AVD Manager]

Olá pessoal, eu estou utilizando o processador intel x86 com uma Device padrão android 4.1.2. Apenas fiz a instalação alone do SDK e startei o Device. Como pode ver o display fica todo desconfigurado.

Comment: sei que não responde a sua pergunta, mas tenta usar o Genymotion pra teste do Android. Eu uso somente ele e garanto que é muito bom. Sem falar que é mais leve que os outros virtual devices padrões. https://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 1):

Pude notar que você utiliza o windows

1. Baixe o Xamarin Android Player na Versão 0.5.6(ou mais recente)
   [clicando aqui](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/)
2. Instale o Xamarin Android Player (que vai instalar o Oracle VM Virtual Box)
3. Se estiver utilizando o Windows 8.1 ou 10 baixe a ultima versão do VM Virtual Box [clicando aqui](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
4. Atualize o VM Virtual Box
5. Crie o seu novo dispositivo com a API ou versão Android desejada